# Concat string with __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, variadic-macros

I've the following macro:

```
 #define MY_FCT1( id, ... )       \
    FCT( id,__VA_ARGS__ );        \
```

and I want to create a new one to do something like this:

```
 #define MY_FCT2( id, ... )                           \
    MY_FCT1( id, (" %s : ",Name())" "__VA_ARGS__);    \
```

but I get the following error:

> error: expression cannot be used as a function

Anyone have an idea how to solve this issue please?

Comment: I only see that your code is wrong. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: it must add the returned string from Name() function to the given arguments of MY_FCT1

Comment: So simply `MY_FCT1(id, Name(), __VA_ARGS__)`?

Comment: no doesn't work, I get this error: error: expected ')' before 'Name'

Comment: I try this: MY_FCT1( id, " %s : "__VA_ARGS__, Name()); but I get Name() after __VA_ARGS__

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to do. A macro cannot call a function. A macro can yield replacement text which includes a function call, but the function won't be called until runtime.

To add `Name()` to the `__VA_ARGS__` which `MY_FCT1` receives, just add it like a normal argument with a comma.

```
 #define MY_FCT2( id, ... )                           \
    MY_FCT1( id, Name(), __VA_ARGS__);
```

You appear to be trying to use a quoted space character as a concatenation operator. The operator for this (only valid in the replacement text of a macro) is `##`. Eg.

```
#define CAT(x,y) x ## y
//or
#define CAT(x,y) x##y
//                ^ ^    spaces are not relevant here
```